# Перестала работать запись с переполнением в переменную типа Word

Tags: delphi

Очень простой пример работающий на Delphi 10.1 (Berlin) и не работающий на более старших версиях

```
var
  a, b, c: Word;
begin
  a := 297;
  b := 57762;
  c := a * b;
end;
```

в версии 10.1 значение переменной с = 23688 а в более старший out of range
т.е. значение переменных a,b,c являются не word а integer

Comment: и чего вы от коллег хотите? проблема вроде вам понятна, значения не влезают в тип данных. казалось бы, надо использовать тот тип данных, размерность которого позволит проводить подобные вычисления. в чем тогда вопрос?

Comment: А вопрос в чем?

Comment: вопрос в том почему на старых версиях работало а на новых нет

Comment: так результат в старой то не корректный. в новых просто эксепшен падает при переполнении.

Comment: В unsigned word влезают числа максимум до 2 ** 16 - 1, т.е. до 65535, у вас результат явно больше получится. Если вам просто произведение нужно получить, то используйте integer.

Comment: я понимаю, что нужно использовать тип переменной integer. но мне нужно получить на выходе именно то число, что получалось на старых версиях пусть оно и не корректное

Comment: возьмите произведение и занулите старшее слово. ну или возьмите от него младшее. возможно, даже явное приведение к word, спасет вас

Comment: а можно пример? просто я навичек еще

Comment: @Александр `c := (a * b) and 65535` (или 0xFFFF , не в курсе как 16-ричные числа в delphi записываются)

Comment: А можно просто перед вычислениями поставить `{$R-}` (отключить проверку переполнения), а потом включить (`{$R+}`) или пойти и настройках проекта переключить.

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответы всё получилось!!!

Comment: @Александр так что именно помогло?

Comment: @KoVadim, пока остановился на варианте уважаемого insolor  c := (a * b) and 65535 (или 0xFFFF , не в курсе как 16-ричные числа в delphi записываются) но попробовал и вариант с директивой компилятора {$R-} тоже отработало

Comment: можно еще было shl 16, shr 16 =)

Comment: @teran а вот этот вариант не подашел с shr 16, значение на выходе не те, хоть и ошибка пропала

Answer (score 1):

Очень похоже на то, что компилировались с разными настройками.
https://www.gunsmoker.ru/2009/04/delphi_19.html
ищи слова «Overflow checking»

В вашем примере идет переполнение и то, что вы сделали сейчас это игнорирование этого переполнения. Результат операции некорректный (хотя при генерации псевдослучайных чисел, шифровании или хэшировании такое практикуется).

Comment: да именно для шифрования этот кусок и использовался иначе получались числа гиганского размера не помещающиеся даже в переменную int64. А настройки компилятора я никогда не трогаю.